# what should be the youtube custom gadget ssl level

Tags: ssl, youtube

In the youtube brand channel Gadget Developer Guidelines there is a requirement that the gadget must be SSL compliant.
https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1727240?hl=en

My question is what type of SSL level is required. For example is Extended Validation a must or any SSL certificate is sufficient.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any SSL certificate because their level of encryption is just the same, they only differ on how CAs verify them that would definitely increase clients trust making sure that the company is legitimate. There are also other added features on some SSL certificates that made them more expensive.